# Assign a serial number to duplicated values of a vector in R

Tags: r

I would like to assign a serial number to duplicated values of a vector in R without using a for loop as shown in the example below. I have a big data set.
Thanks

```
a<-c("A","B","A","A","B","C","D","E","D")
```

Expected Output:

```
desired.answer<-c(1,1,2,3,2,1,1,1,2)
```

Comment: can you use `dput` to give us an example of your dataset? Preferably with a duplicated value init

Comment: a<-c("A","B","A","A","B","C","D","E","D") 

desired.answer<-c(1,1,2,3,2,1,1,1,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data you provided you can use the `group_by` function from the `dplyr` package to then assign serial numbers independently to each group.

```
data.frame(value = c("A","B","A","A","B","C","D","E","D") ) %>% 
  group_by(value) %>% 
  mutate(serial_number = 1:n())
```

```
A tibble: 9 x 2
Groups:   value [5]
 value serial_number
 <chr>         <int>
1 A                 1
2 B                 1
3 A                 2
4 A                 3
5 B                 2
6 C                 1
7 D                 1
8 E                 1
9 D                 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how "big" your data set is, but you could also consider using `data.table` for management. Here you can set `serial_number` to values from 1 to the number of elements in a group (`.N`), after grouping by each common value in your vector.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a)
dt[, serial_number := 1:.N, by = a]
```

Or, using `rowid` as suggested by @markus:

```
dt[, serial_number := rowid(a)]
```

**Output**

```
   a serial_number
1: A             1
2: B             1
3: A             2
4: A             3
5: B             2
6: C             1
7: D             1
8: E             1
9: D             2
```

Comment: You can use `data.table::rowid(a)` here.